# Why do forward slashes get stripped on Blowfish encryption?

Tags: java, blowfish

Consider the following method that performs Blowfish encryption:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

private static String encryptString(String value, String key)
{
    String encryptedString = "";
    if (value != null)
    {
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "Blowfish");
        try
        {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/PKCS#5");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            encryptedString = new String(Hex.encodeHex(encrypted));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Show error
        }
    }
    return encryptedString;
}
```

The String that I want to encode contains forward slashes. When I try to encode for example "http://www.google.com/Foo", for some reason when I decode it, the forward slashes are stripped, e.g. "http:www.google.comFoo".

What could be a possible cause for this and how could this be prevented?

Comment: You've posted your encryption code, but your complaint appears to be in your decryption code.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear. There is NO decryption code, as I send my data encrypted over HTTP. However for debugging reasons, I use this website to decrypt my string: https://webnet77.net/cgi-bin/helpers/blowfish.pl

Comment: A remark better add the encoding to: `value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` and on decryption `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF:_8)`. Slash (and plus) are part of standard Base64, There exists an URL safe Base64 variant that uses other characters. I cannot imagine how, but maybe that Base64 was used on _one_ side.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an error in an external website, and has nothing to do with given code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an error of the website (https://webnet77.net/cgi-bin/helpers/blowfish.pl) you're using to check the encrypted text.

Try encrypting the text (`http://www.google.com/Foo`) on that site, and you'll see that it strips the slashes. Java doesn't.

---

Other issues:

- What is the value of the `key` parameter?

  If it is a hex encoding of the Blowfish key, then `getBytes()` is entirely wrong, since you need to hex decode it, rather than the code page conversion you're currently doing.

  `SecretKeySpec` needs a `byte[]` because a key is a binary value, and cannot be stored a plain text.
- `Blowfish/ECB/PKCS#5` is not a valid cipher in JDK.

  `Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5PADDING` is.
- If your `value` parameter can ever contain anything other than plain ASCII, then `value.getBytes()` is inadequate. You should *always* specify the code page when converting a string into bytes.

  You can specify `"US-ASCII"` to enforce ASCII only, or specify the code page required by the server, but `"UTF-8"` is generally a good choice.

Comment: Although the problem DID exist with my algorithm, your comments helped me fix it. Particularly, changing to UTF-8 encoding and to Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5PADDING did the trick.